# Best Android launcher for productivity

Tags: email, calendar, android, mobile

I'm looking for an Android launcher designed for productivity.

I was a huge fan of [Slide Screen](http://slidescreenhome.com), a minimalist launcher with all needed information in one single slidable screen.
Sadly, the project is no longer maintained, hence not usable anymore.

I know that there exist many different launchers supporting external themes, but I don't have any experience on possible productivity focused themes or launchers.

By considering productivity and minimalism, what Android themes/launchers do you suggest?

Comment: What specific criteria are you looking for when you talk about *productivity and minimalism*? You also should not ask for *best*, that is opinion-based. BTW There is an SE site for software recommendations: [SoftwareRecs.SE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [FlowHome](http://larvalabs.com/flowhome/) (in beta version), created by Larva Labs, the same creators of Slide Screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Smart launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ginlemon.flowerfree&hl=en)

Some of the most notable features in SL are:

- exclusive home screen layouts: try out the flower and the honeycomb layouts;
- global AI powered search bar: search in apps, contacts and web.
- smart turn off: your screen automatically turns off when lay down your phone;
- on screen notifications: see which app needs attention (requires plugin);
- knock off: turn off the screen with a double tap (requires plugin);
- gestures support: up to 10 different gestures!
- hide apps: remove any app from your app grid (works also with system apps)
- security: select the apps you want to hide and protect them with a PIN.
- popup widgets: double tap on an icon to show the widget you chose;
- low resources usage: SL is optimized to work greatly even on older devices and to use as less memory and battery as possible in any situation.
- great wallpaper selection: new wallpaper proposed every day.
- custom lock screens: personalize and add features to your lock screen;

Hope this helps

Comment: I've also found FlowHome, created by the same developers of Slide Screen. See http://larvalabs.com/flowhome/

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.launcher) have a sliding home screen.